# Вызов внутреннего скрипта используя GNU Parallel (csh)

Tags: linux, bash, циклы, распараллеливание

Вопрос по поводу GNU Parallel. Как внести внутренний файл (в csh) в GNU Parallel? Также очень важно чтобы GNU Parallel осуществлял параллельную обработку ( по строкам `awk '{print $0}' $1`) по файлу `data.in`. Иными словами он должен быть последовательным во внутреннем коде (внутренний код это петля и код должен выполняться последовательно без распилок на команды и т.д.) но запустить его надо (код) несколько раз одновременно для обработки всех файлов указанных в `data.in` (файлов 15 значит и параллельных процессов должно быть 15). Код с 55 до 266 строки внесен в отдельный файл. Ссылка на код [GMT](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/projects/gmt5sar/repository/entry/branches/5.2_KF/gmtsar/csh/preproc_batch_tops.csh).

При этом файл `data.in` уже "задан" в код (выше ссылка на код). Буду рад любой помощи.

Мой неработающий вариант

```
#!/bin/csh -f
# код с 0 до 55 строки
`awk '{print $0}' $1` | parallel loop2.csh ::: fff
```

Внутри loop2.csh

```
#!/bin/csh -f
fff() {
# команды с 56 до 266 строки
}
```

Ошибка

```
parallel: Command not found.
```

Оригинальный код, ключевый момент для вопроса

```
# loop over all the acquisitions    
  foreach line (`awk '{print $0}' $1`)
```

Это вообще реально провернуть? Так как `csh` не поддерживает функции.

Comment: Если за пару дней ответа не будет — маякните, назначу награду.

Comment: А вообще "parallel: Command not found" намекает, что нужная программа или не установлена, или не находится (нет в PATH, например). Просто `which parallel` что показывает?

Comment: Выдает `~/bin/parallel` Да и с путями все нормально. Если без `sudo su` то он выдает путь к файлу и сам файл - отказано в доступе. Просто сам вопрос в том как сделать чтобы он видел команду в другом файле. Да и реально ли это вообще

Comment: "видел команду в другом файле" - `parallel csh loop2.csh`?

Comment: Не так выразился. Нужно задать аргумент (во внутреннем файле команды и их задаешь аргументом) чтобы через него gnu parallel уже обрабатывал. Ну или как нибудь по другому.